# How do i get the smallest/biggest number out of an array of intgers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, numbers, return

The task given is to return the smallest and biggest number as an array from an array of random numbers:

> the function called 'major and minor' receives as argument an array of
> numbers called 'numbers' and must return an array containing the
> smallest number in the array 'numbers' at position zero and the
> largest number in the array
>
> number in the position 1.
>
> Example:
>
> minorMajor([4, 6, 1, 7, 15]) should return [1, 15]
>
> given that 1 is the smallest number (minor) inside the array [4, 6,
> 1, 7, 15]
>
> and 15 is the biggest number (major) inside the array [4, 6, 1, 7,
> 15]

My attempt so far:

```js
function menorMayor(num) {
  [3, 7, 4, 2, 8]
  for (let i = 0; i <= num.legth; i++)
    index = num
}
if (0 > [i]) return ('minor');
else if (0 < [i]) return ('major');
```

However when submitting this the terminal(console) say´s failure that I " *should return the smallest numbers, and bigger numbers*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two function that exist in Javascript; Math.min() and Math.max()
You can use them in this code like this:

```js
function menorMayor(num){
    array = [3,7,4,2,8]
    if (!array.includes(num)) return console.log("That number is not in array list.")
    if (Math.min(...array) === num) return console.log("That number is minor number of array.")
    if (Math.max(...array) === num) return console.log("That number is major number of array.")
    return console.log("This number is neither the major nor the minor number.")
}

menorMayor(num)
```

You can visit [this](https://stackabuse.com/javascript-get-min-and-max-element-of-array/) Web Site for understand those 2 functions.

Comment: this work but i had to add some "array-organizer" and some things and that was all!, thanks!

Comment: Generally, links to unofficial documentation are discouraged. Links to MDN are much more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```js
function minMax(arr) {
  let mini = arr[0];
  let max = arr[0];
  let result = [];
  arr.forEach(num => {
    if (num > max) {
      max = num
    }
    else if (num < mini) {
      mini = num
    }
  });
  result.push(mini);
  result.push(max)
  return result;
}

console.log(minMax([2, 5, 32, 12, 45]))
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code? People learn best when they aren't just looking at a big block of code they don't understand. This is especially true for a homework question.